# What is the type of this plane?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-identification, private-jets

I tried looking with aircraft tag on engine but no answers. I just need to find the type of this jet.

[image: another, most recent photo of it]

[image: some kind of older photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a [Bombardier Challenger 600 (CL-600-2A12)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Challenger_600_series) as [per the op-specs of this 135 charter](https://charterpad.com/company_files/102/4a410ce198c0892224631eaa6e122299.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily find this out by searching for the tail number, N97SG, which is analogous to the license plate of a car.  It's a [Bombardier Challenger 600 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Challenger_600_series) business jet.